# $model->validate() not shows error with out filling the form in yii

Tags: php, forms, yii

I have created login form in yii using authenticate functionality.

After submit the login form with out enter username and password, it directly goes to the redirect url.

It doesn't show the error message. I am not familiar in yii. So I couldn't find the solution for this.

Here is my controller code for login form

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'layout10';
    $model = new LoginForm;
    //exit;
    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login($_POST['LoginForm']))

            $url = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()."/admin/product_name";

        Yii::app()->getRequest()->redirect($url);
        //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }

    $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Here is the model page for login

```
class LoginForm extends CActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @return Users the static model class
     */

    private $_identity;


    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(

            array(' password, username,' , 'required', 'on'=>'login' ),

        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(

        );
    }


    public function login( $id, $password = "" )
    {

        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($username = $id ,$password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
        //Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,3600*24*30);

        if(Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,0*0*0))
        {
            //echo $this->_identity->errorMessage;
                        return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::app()->user->setState('error', $this->_identity->errorMessage);
            return false;
        }


    }


    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'username' => 'User',
            'password' => 'Last Name',

        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);




        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the useridentity in components

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
   private $_id;
   public function authenticate()
   {
        $record=LoginForm::model()->find(array(
            'condition'=>'username =:username',
            'params'=>array(':username'=>$this->username)
       )); 

       if($record===null)
       {
           $this->_id='user Null';
           $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
       }
       else if($record->E_PASSWORD!==$this->password)            // here I compare db password with passwod field
       {   
           $this->_id=$this->username;
           $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
       }


       else
       {  
          $this->_id=$record['username'];
           $this->setState('title', $record['username']);
           $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;

       }
       return !$this->errorCode;
   }

   public function getId()       //  override Id
   {

       return $this->_id;
   }
}
```

Here is the view page for login

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>


<fieldset>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user red"></i></span>
         <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('id'=>'example-username2','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username')); ?>



    </div><?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div><br>

    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock red"></i></span>

         <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('id'=>'example-username2','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password')); ?>

    </div><?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <p class="center col-md-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Please tell How to validate the form in model. Now no error message displayed.

Comment: you have login scenario in rules...  so use $model = new LoginForm('login')... may be it wil show u errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for watching errors also you can use:

```
var_dump($model->getErrors());
```

and next

```
$model->login($_POST['LoginForm']);
```

I think you don't need the pass POST variable because model already have this params

maybe you just change the login method like this:

```
public function login()
{

    $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->id ,$this->password);
    $this->_identity->authenticate();
    //Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,3600*24*30);

    if(Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,0*0*0))
    {
        //echo $this->_identity->errorMessage;
                    return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('error', $this->_identity->errorMessage);
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thnx for immediate response. I have changed the given code and display var_dump($model->getErrors());. It shows  Following O/P 
array(0) { }. After changing the code, it doesn't show the error.